# Load new jsx renders into existing Div

Tags: html, reactjs, render, jsx

My goal is to render different pages with different layouts to one div on my index page. The idea is that only one div ("create-focus") changes and I want the other pieces to only have to load once. 
This is a proof-of-concept so everything that I am building is local (I have no addresses to redirect to. Only local files to import.)

I have an index.jx as thus:

```
<div class="col-md-12">             
    <div id="create-header"></div>
    <div id="create-top-banner"></div>              
    <div id="create-menu"></div>
    <div id="create-focus"></div>   
    <div id="create-footer"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to replace the id "create-focus" with new html from another jsx :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./AdBanners.css";

class AdBanners extends Component {

  render() {
    return (        
        <div className="AdBannerBody" id="ad-banners" ref={this.myRef}>
            <h2>Stuff and Things</h2>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AdBanners;

const wrapper = document.getElementById("create-adBanner");
wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<AdBanners />, wrapper) : false;
```

I have tried to load just the html, but it simply prints the code to my screen as text. Do I need to run another render call? How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very good what you're trying to do, is it to set the inner html of the div "create focus"?

take a look at:

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing ReactDOM.render.  The second argument should be a reference to a normal HTML element you want to render your element as the child of.  So in your case you would want to call:

```
ReactDOM.render(<AdBanners />, document.getElementById("create-focus"))
```

Although I'm not sure this is exactly what you're trying to do.  The setup for this app seems very strange to me.

Comment: This is a big project of me rebuilding a webpage for a client and learning React at the same time. I followed this tutorial (https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/#How_to_set_up_React_webpack_and_Babel_setting_up_the_project) for my setup and have expanded from there.
Don't know if this is best-practice or not?

Comment: If you're new to React I highly recommend using [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started).  It's the easiest way to start making a react app because it gives you boilerplate code to work off of and it has webpack already set up.